# Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader?

Tags: python, debian, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
and I get this message

```
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

How do I start to set it up in Debian 9?

Comment: How did you start? I.e., how did you install virtualenvwrapper?

Comment: all dependencies with virtualenwrapper is installed with pip.

Comment: pip, not pip3? pip is for Python 2.7, but you error shows python3.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to install virtualenvwrapper separately for different versions of Python:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

The first one is for Python 2.7, the second for Python 3.

Comment: -bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory, but solved original error in question.

Comment: That's strange. `pip install` should install both the module and shell scripts. Did both `pip install` finish successfully?

Comment: I uninstalled for pip and installed successfully for python 3.

Answer (score 32):

Installing virtualenv by both, `pip` and `pip3` doesn't make any sense because installing it by any one shows virutalenvwrapper in both, `pip list` and `pip3 list`.

The right way is to copy the following code in your `~/.bashrc`.

> VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=$(which python3)

NOTE: Use the python version you want to use, in my case it's `python3`.

Comment: running `which python3` in my terminal and then using it as
`[which python3 path]/virtualenvwrapper.sh`
did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

you need to change  VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 to
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
for MacOS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: for me on Mac it's source `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Answer (score 0):

This have solved my issue on macOS Monterey 2022:

Terminal

```
cd
nano .bashrc
```

Code in file

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs 
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

save it

```
CTRL + x
```

```
y
```